# Configuring MinGW-w64 with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I have installed MinGW-w64 on my Windows 8 machine using the c++ compiler within Code::Blocks 12.11.

I tried to compile a program using one of the conversion functions and got the following error message:

> main.cpp|22|error: 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'|

I have setup the directories in the Compiler Settings and Toolchain executables.  I am not sure why the program is not compiling.  Any help would be welcome.

```
int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int* pNum = &num2;
    string strTest = "6";

    cout << strTest << endl;

    std::cout << std::stoi("32") << std::endl;


    num1 = 3;
    *pNum = 5;

    cout << "Finished" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are using the TDM C++ toolchain that comes with C::B, I suggest replacing it with the one at https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: "One of the conversion functions" -- Which one?

Comment: The function is stoi().  I am sure others do not work as well.